# When do we need to use .NET Remoting?

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-remoting

When do we need to use .NET Remoting? What is the Serialization usage in .NET Remoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remotely and transparently call functions. Serializable objects must be used as arguments because they need to be reconstructed on the other side of the line.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Remoting is used for communication between diffrent [AppDomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [Contexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.contextboundobject.aspx) in a .NET Process or you can use it for communication between two .NET Processes.